# React native text inside views with flexDirect : "row" is not wrapping

Tags: react-native

I have a text inside a view that has flex direction set to 'row', which cause the text inside the view is not wrapping.

How can I get the text to wrap correctly?

my code looks like

```
<View style={BaseStyle.formRow}>
    <ImageLoadingIndicator
        style={BaseStyle.formRowImage}
        source={{uri: business.profileImage.url}}
        />
    <View style={[BaseStyle.container, {marginLeft: 5, alignItems: 'flex-start', flexWrap: 'wrap'}]}>
        <Text style={{fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{business.name}</Text>
        <Text
            style={{marginTop: 3}}>{Address.generateAddressStringFromComponent(business)}</Text>
    </View>
</View>
```

where my styles are:

```
var Style = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
    formRow:{
        flex: 1,
        width: SCREEN_WIDTH - 20,
        flexDirection:'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        alignItems: 'center',
        marginTop: 8,
        marginBottom: 8,
        paddingRight: 10,
        paddingLeft: 10,
        flexWrap: 'wrap'
    },
    formRowImage:{
        height:60,
        width:60,
        borderRadius: 4
    },
});
```

Comment: i think the code is fine you just need to fix some of the code issues where u need to add ',' after container stylesheet (before formRow starting)

Comment: @PramodMg thanks for your suggestion, I tried remove it but still not wrapping the text :(

Comment: I set up an example project here ( https://rnplay.org/apps/NaUUBg ) with your above code, it looks like the text is wrapping fine. Is there some different functionality you are looking for? Thanks.

Comment: @NaderDabit Thanks for the example. I tried separate these codes to a separate component and the text is wrapping fine, no sure what was the issue.